# How to get back that satisfying chest burn?

Tags: weightlifting, push-ups, chest, cables, burn

I can shock the chest muscles with supersets and hitting different angles using cables, weights and push-ups in supersets, but I can't make it burn anymore during the workout.

I do varying inclines on the Smith machine, flyes, incline hammer presses, crossovers, etc., but I can't seem to recapture that beautiful burn I get with ab and arm workouts. I work to failure, and I'm using moderate weights, high reps (12-15), several sets (5-8) and holding briefly on adduction. My chest is getting big, but there is no burn anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: See: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24454/8828

Comment: Thanks for that link. I saw that too, specifically "will most likely come back once you change it up". But instead of DOMS, I'm looking for that burn in the gym.

Comment: Try "down the racks". Sets to failure of db presses with 100lb (or whatever), then 90's, then 80's, etc, etc. It's funny when you're doing it with 20's and dying.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to introduce resistance bands on post-fatigue.

[image: cables]

The weights are already moderate, and more weight isn't the answer.

Cables and weights, and hitting different angles are fantastic, and the results show, but using strong resistance bands in place of cable-crossovers increases the resistance right near the end of the adduction.

Holding for a second at the top of each rep produces an amazing burn.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions would be:

1. Try using a normal bench press bench (non smith machine) for normal, incline, and decline bench press.
2. Get a spotter and do high weights with low reps or even do some one-rep maxs