# Chronic Hamstring Problem

Tags: injury-prevention, sports, hamstring, soccer

I play soccer once or twice a week and always seem to pull my hamstring once or twice a season.  This has been happening for years.  Even when I was in college and in shape I was struggling with this.

Is there any way to avoid this or tips that can help prevent this?  I have tried tight compression shorts and icing.

Answer (score 1):

Soccer is a fairly injury prone sport. It's great that people are playing sports, but I've seen studies suggesting that it's the most injury producing of team sports, beyond even tackle football. [Looking at Australia, here are some metrics being reported](http://sma.org.au/resources-advice/sport-fact-sheets/football-soccer-fact-sheet/):

> The rate of injury for football players is up to 35 injuries per 1,000
>   playing hours.

That's more than 1 injury per 30 hours of playing. Obviously a lot depends on what you refer to as an "injury", but either way the sport you're playing is notoriously hard on the body.

A good strength training program would take you far though. While it may not stop your injuries, [strength training will lessen the amount, make them less severe, and give you a better route through recovery.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3633121)

> Resistance training in addition to increasing muscular strength and
>   hypertrophy may also aid in the prevention of injuries. Research
>   indicates that resistance training promotes growth and/or increases in
>   the strength of ligaments, tendons, tendon to bone and ligament to
>   bone junction strength, joint cartilage and the connective tissue
>   sheaths within muscle. Studies involving humans and animal models also
>   demonstrate resistance training can cause increased bone mineral
>   content and therefore may aid in prevention of skeletal injuries.
>   Investigations to date suggest resistance training can aid in injury
>   prevention.

I'd recommend a basic program like [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs) or [Strong Lifts 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/). Since you're paricularly having problems with your hamstrings, I'd supplement with a couple of exercises in particular:

- [Single leg Romanian deadlift](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/GluteusMaximus/DBSingleLegStiffLegDeadlift.html). It's a big name for a relatively simple exercise, but I bet the first time you try it you'll topple over. Running and soccer are particularly single-leg sports: one is on the ground while the other is in the air.
- [Good mornings](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Hamstrings/BBGoodMorning.html). Do these after you've spent a few weeks doing one of the linked barbell training programs above. Initially, they will give you a wicked case of [DOMS](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19157/7091), so keep the weight lighter than you can possibly imagine: even an unweighted Olympic bar (20kg/45lbs) will be plenty. These are one of the more difficult exercises to perform, so buddy up with a professional trainer (maybe who can squat 2x their body weight), and have them check your form.