# Is weight loss possible without cardio?

Tags: weight-loss

I have been advised by my doctor not to do any running, dancing type of exercise which puts stress on my legs due to a leg condition. Being on bed rest for nearly a month and a very sedentary lifestyle after that I have gained a lot of weight. Is it possible to lose weight without any cardio? If yes, please suggest some exercises.

Comment: Yes. Stop eating.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's important to point out that [strength training is a better form of fat loss than "cardio"](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19117/7091).

Beyond that, taking in less calories is ***vastly*** easier then "burning" them. To make that clear, the average bagel has 250 calories, which is the rough equivalent of 50 minutes of walking (180lb person, 3mph pace). I mean seriously, which is easier to do: walk an hour or not eat a bagel?

For anyone looking to lose weight, the priorities go:

1. Diet. Less calories in than needed.
2. Strength training. As referenced in the study above, boosting your basal metabolic rate is far more relevant for anyone but the most active of endurance athletes.
3. Aerobic activity, aka "cardio".

In your case, I'd focus on getting your diet locked in. That will lower your body weight which in turn will make life easier on you to move around. With your doctor, start looking into body weight training (including yoga) and go from there.

Comment: It may be more intensity than type related: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24486/all-activity-is-the-same-for-weight-loss

Comment: But if you are doing strength training, or any weightlifting, don't they say that you need to eat MORE to see results?

Comment: @Luciano that's if you want to pack on serious muscle mass. Most novice lifters will see rather immediate (~6 month) results regardless of their diet. The beginning phase of lifting is pretty much the only time you can lose fat and pack on muscle.

Comment: Also be prepared to actually "look" fatter for a small while. As the muscle grows, but is not at a mass to use all the excess fat, it may make the fat look like it's grown.
Imagine doing a lot of core work, increase in ab size will push your gut out a bit. Totally temporary though

Answer (score 13):

Swimming. There's *always* swimming. It's easy on joints and bones, and is both a cardiovascular exercise, and a strength exercise.

Other than that, you're going to have to look to your diet to lose weight. Remember, weight loss happens when over time, your consumed calories amount to less than your spent calories.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to learn swimming all this time too. :)

Comment: "There's always swimming" - one of the things I love about swimming. Bad legs? Focus on pull. Bad arms? Focus on kick. I don't know of a sport that's more flexible than swimming.

Answer (score 7):

It is harder to lose weight without exercise.  You only lose weight if you burn more calories than you consume and if you are sedentary your metabolism will slow down you may be burning less than 1200 calories a day.   If you gained a lot of weight then you are consuming a lot of calories.  Start with eat healthy - vegetables and minimal fat.  A healthy diet has less calories and also helps keep your metabolism going.   You have swimming and arm exercises.  Could you do a stationary bike?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with strength training and control of diet which @eric suggested.

Along with that Yoga has some breathing techniques called pranayams. These are sitting and breathing techniques which synergies the body. Brasthikriya, kapalbhati and anulom vilom are few of the pranayam techniques in yogic literature.

you can find some information in this link: 
http://www.yogicwayoflife.com/pranayama-for-weight-loss/

I would suggest you find some youtube videos for these.

Answer (score -1):

Weight loss happens when your body doesn't have enough energy from food. It's forced to use it's own reserves to survive.

So yes, if you're in a calorie deficit you will lose weight. However, you'll be eating much less than an active person.