# Best online program for fat loss

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines, body-fat

I have come across programs like Kris gethin and jym stoppani....I want to lose fat and build muscle...I need a weight loss of around 20kilos too....I would ask will the program help me with my goal...because I will be joining the gym for the first time and have no experience with weight training before.

Comment: Please search this site. This question has been asked and answered dozens of times.

Comment: I checked that....but I guess that was not answerd for a first time gym goer

Answer (score 1):

There are a few existing question and answers that I'd point you towards.

- [Spot reduction is a myth](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/Myths.html). Our age, sex, and genetics control how fat is stored and released.
- [Strength training is better for weight loss than aerobic cardio](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/19117#19117). This seems incredibly counter-intuitive, but it's true and the evidence supports it.

[The priorities you need to engage are reducing calories, strength training, and aerobic cardio, in order](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24500/7091).