# Walking my way to FATness?

Tags: exercise, fat, walking

I started walking 3 miles per day around October of 2015, before 2015 I did swimmimg , biking, treadmill, crosstraining and adding weights to my ankles and all sorts of things to shift weight.

I am still walking 3 miles per day. Since I started I have lost very little in weight and I dont eat much already. I am not a cake, chocolate, crisp (Potato chips), fizzy drinks or junk food addict. I was raised on vegetables, meat, fruit, juice, and occasional biscuits (cookies) for a treat and I honestly mean occasional. I dont drink alcohol except on a rare social event in the family which is truly rare and then I'll only drink to tipsy merry no more.

I gave up smoking 6 years ago this year, yet I have battled with my weight all my bloody life and I'm quite sick of making an effort for no true results. Some times my thyroid doesnt work correctly, doctor says my brain is not calling for the thyroid to work like it should. I also have an iron deficiency, I cant hold on to iron as it doesnt absorb, it leaves my body and so i have to take iron in tablet form and I am now 15st,13 and 3/4 in weight (About 206 lbs), I was 16 st 13.

Even though I have been walking since Oct 2015, my legs still burn badly when walking and I'm breathless when there is an incline in the pavement!

What's my issue why cant I shed weight like others I see exercising by walking? Why does it still hurt too?

Comment: If your thyroid doesn't work and you say you are having weight issues as in you're gaining weight, I think your problem is hypothyroidism, which is what I have. Hypothyroidism is related to weight-gain, laziness, and slow metabolism. You don't mention you're taking meds for it so if you don't I strongly suggest you to get tested and see what your dosage should be.

Comment: You may not eat much in terms of volume, but I suspect that you're eating more in terms of energy (what really counts) than you think you are. Juice for instance tends to be both high in sugar and calories, meaning it's easy to over consume and thus make it harder to lose weight. Try tracking what you eat for a week or two to see how much you're actually consuming.

Comment: Thank you for replies just to clarify a couple of things,the juice i drink is cordial as in watered down with bottled water not tap and i do it very weak i dont like it strong,and the thyroid problems i am getting bloods taken each month for the gp to decide if i need treatment for it or not, the problem with this is if the thyroid is only slightly out theyll do nothing for me but from what i have learnt it only has to be slightly out to throw the whole body into chaos? good idea with the tracking food i could be over doing it without actually thinking so yes thats worth monitoring thank you!

Comment: You can find a list of food tracking sites with a quick Google search. If you have a phone, most of these places even offer a free app for doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone might give you a better answer, but I'll point to [some existing answers that you may want to consider](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24500/7091).

In short, diet has the largest impact on your body fat stores. Unless you have meticulously counted your calories for several days (2 weeks is pretty good), then you really can't say that you're eating properly.

You don't need to count every calorie for the rest of your life, but you do need to do it long enough to understand, calorie-by-calorie, what you're putting into your body.