# Advise on Exercise machine for weight loss

Tags: weight-loss, exercise-equipment

After baby number 2, I weigh 70kg and am trying to lose weight ideally to 60kg. Can you please advise on which exercise machine to purchase for cardio. Something that does not take up a lot of space as I live in an apartment. I have been thinking of a mini exercise bike but I am not sure how effective this will be. Thanks

Comment: Good luck on your efforts. You may want to take a look at this, regarding the effectiveness of cardio for weight loss. http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/is-weight-loss-possible-without-cardio/24500#24500

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a purchase recommendation for exercise equipment.  And, according to the Help, that's off-topic.

Comment: @rrirower - I'm actually going back and forth on whether this is off topic. "Gadget and gear used during exercise". I think if the OP were to give a bit more detail about the fitness routine she is thinking of starting and time/space available, it would be squarely on target, as we could discuss the pros and cons of specific items related to that program. As it is written, yes, it leans more towards the off topic side, but I think it could be rescued.

Comment: If she took out "to purchase", then it would be squarely on topic. I'm keeping it open.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest foregoing the machine altogether and focusing on these two things:

- Try and find some kind of fun, 30 minute or so, workout plan that includes a mix of resistance training and cardio. Do this ~5 days a week.
- Reign in your diet.  A lot of these workout plans come with meal plans and suggestions.  Small changes can go a long way.

If you keep your calories roughly 25% less than your maintenance calories ( not lower or it'll make you feel like crap ) and workout for a few months you'll most assuredly get where you want to be.

There are a ton of free workout plans available online.  Beachbody workouts are also very solid in my opinion.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Exercise bike is great as it's not that hard on the body like a treadmill is. You can perform hiit or steady state cardio on it. Bare in mind weight loss is achieved through calorie deficit and exercise is just a means of assisting in creating a deficit. If you eat more than you burn it won't make a difference what exercise you do, you won't lose weight

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion (I'm not a physician nor a personal trainer)if you want to lose weight the better option is (as other have pointed out)changing your diet (that could just be reducing the daily calories. But since you asked for a machine I'll suggest a rower. Why a rower and not an exercise bike or treadmill ? 
Because it's equally (if not more) effective at cardio conditioning and it makes you use more muscle groups (you are pushing with your legs, pulling with your arms and back, flexing your core to stabilize yourself ...). More muscles recruitment (in a simplified view) mean more calories burned. If you have space issues you could buy a foldable rower