# My body has adapted to walking

Tags: weight-loss, walking

I started dieting and walking about 4 months ago, building up to around 60-70 miles a week, and lost 11kg/23lbs up to the middle of May ...

But the last month I have had no weight loss so I think my body has adapted...

If I carry on walking is it likely that the weight loss will start again, or do I have to change to swimming and gym work?

thanks

Comment: I'd read up on strength training and diet's impact to fat loss: it's much more than cardio. https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/is-weight-loss-possible-without-cardio/24500#24500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walking with less weight is obviously easier, so you are now burning fewer calories for the same distance. It does feel easier and you are not getting out of breath any more, doesn’t it? (Good things! I’d like to point out) Try to increase speed and inclination (e.g. walk over some hills or steps) or change the exercise (e.g. running or cycling where you can increase intensity almost infinitely).

If it’s only about losing weight I agree with Eric Kaufman in the comments, strength training and diet are easier. I always get very (unproportionally) hungry from (intense) cardio and it does take a lot of time. But do what you enjoy, because otherwise you won’t stick with it.