# Gaining internal hip rotation good for touching toes?

Tags: hamstring

My problem is tight or rather too stretched hamstrings, so i'm trying to solve this problem. Hamstring stretches make me feel unstable so i think they are tight already. I HAVE A KNOT LEFT LOWER BACK FROM PAST INJURY, but no real pain.

I've been making alot of progress with my lordosis/anterior knee pain after doing various exercises.

So basically i now have decent external hip rotation, but seing as i have never done any stretches for gaining internal rotation, i think i may be tight there.

So i have one simple question : Will a stretch like the Lying knee to knee stretch, give me some hamstring length? (or at least not hurt my lordosis/APT condition)

Plus any other advice for gaining some hamstring length and stride much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you're really tight, the [lying knee to knee stretch](http://running.competitor.com/2014/03/video/monday-minute-lying-knee-to-knee-stretch_4863) will get felt in your hamstrings as well. So if you need more flexibility in that area, you'll get it, although it's not really a "hamstring stretch" in the purest sense.

[I answered a similar question a few weeks ago](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25197/difficulty-maintaining-activation-of-hamstrings-after-pcl-tear/25198#25198), and would recommend reading that one as well, particularly the [single leg deadlift](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/GluteusMaximus/DBSingleLegStiffLegDeadlift.html) part.

It's worth pointing out that most of the internal hip rotation is done via the [glutes and tensor fasciae latae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_internal_rotators_of_the_human_body). I'd be very concerned about overdoing isolation work in the hips: it's not an area you want to create imbalances (like what you currently have). As an assistance exercise in concert with more balanced strength training, it's fine.

If I wanted to build up strength in internal hip rotation, I would as such focus on strengthening my posterior chain through a full range of motion. This will stretch and strengthen you in a healthy and balanced way.

- Deadlifts. Hard to beat, focus on internally rotating your hips, especially in the last half of the lift, to really activate those glutes.
- Single leg deadlift. Terrific for identifying imbalances and forcing you to... balance.
- [Lying clams](http://bretcontreras.com/the-band-side-lying-clam/) (with bands) frequently as they engage a lot of the hips and don't fry you for other things.
- [The band-at-toes-level sumo and monster walk](http://bretcontreras.com/band-placement-during-walking-glute-activation-drills-2/).

Comment: I keep feeling like this answer has external and internal rotation mixed up. My thighs rotate outward when I squeeze my glute max in the deadlift and spin the floor, and I think of reverse clams as being the inward rotators.