# Why Doms again?

Tags: doms, stress

I do weight lifting once a week starting with a warm up set of 2kg, then sets of 14kg, and then drop sets. The last time I did was the 17th of October and after that my muscles were sore and now again lifting on the 30th of October I am sore again. I don't understand why my muscles are sore again. I tried to lift 16kg with a 2kg warm up as before and was barely able to do a 3rd rep at 16kg. I know DOMS happens when your body does a new effort of which it is not used to. After the DOMS goes away, does it mean that I have gained more strength than before and my body will adapt to the weight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between the 17th and 30th of October, almost two weeks have passed. That's far too long of a time period for your muscles to really get used to the movements and resistance.

If you want to avoid DOMS, and make better progress, you need to consider working out a lot more often. A good place to start is every 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

> After the DOMS goes away, does it mean that I have gained more
>   strength than before and my body will adapt to the weight?

You might benefit from reading my response to a [similar question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/27365/why-i-never-feel-doms-on-my-abs/27370#27370). Although the question refers to a specific body part, the science behind my answer is still the same.  To quote from that answer:

> Current research indicates that there is [no causal relationship](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221841567_Does_Exercise-Induced_Muscle_Damage_Play_a_Role_in_Skeletal_Muscle_Hypertrophy) to
>   assume that DOMS/EIMD is a valid indicator for muscular progress
>   (hypertrophy). As a result, I would suggest using a different
>   indicator for your progress.