# What if I don't get DOMS, not enough workout?

Tags: training, doms

So I follow a 3 day routine (routine makes me repeat 2 muscle groups a week)which consists of(I'm unsure of some of the names of the exercises, sorry in advance):

Day one:

- Bench press/Dumbbell Flys(IDK if that's the correct spelling) [4x10(4 sets of ten reps each, maybe formatting is the other way around, not sure)]
- Incline bench press/cable flys [4x10]
- Declined dumbbell press [4x10]
- Dips/Pull overs [4x10]
- Push downs/Skull crushers [4x10]
- Close grip bench press/ Seated dips [4x10]
- Pull downs/ Kick backs(unsure of the name) [4x10]
- Dumbbell shoulder press/lateral raises [4x10]
- Barbell shoulder press/ barbell upright rows [4x10]
- Variations(3) of rear delt raises [21x3]
- 30-40 min low intensity cardio

Day two:

- Squats/leg extensions [4x10]
- Leg press/Hamstring curls [4x10]
- Dumbbell steps/standing hamstring curls [4x10]
- Dumbbell lunges/hamstring curls [4x12]
- Standing calf raises [9x10]
- Seated calf raises [9x10]
- Variations of ab exercises [4x10]

Day three:

- Power clings [4x10]
- Barbell rows/wide grip pull down [4x10]
- T bar rows/Close grip pull down [4x10]
- Seated cable rows/One arm dumbbell row [4x10]
- Barbell curls/Incline dumbbell curls [4x10]
- Preacher curls/ barbell concentration curls [4x10]
- Standing curls(variations)/Bicep curl machine [4x10]
- Upper Barbell wrist curls [5x10]
- Lower barbell wrist curls [5x10]
- Dumbbell Handshake [4x10]
- Wrist roller [4 Reps, length of cable]
- 30-40 min low intensity cardio

I rest 30-45 secs between each new set and 50sec-1min between series, and I do get incredibly tired, the thing is I don't feel sore afterwards, I do feel tired, but not the usual sore that comes from working out. I don't know if it's a bad routine, or my body's fault. Can anyone please explain to me what could be the reason of me not getting those DOMS? (IMHO I think DOMS are awesome, it's like rewarding pain)

Comment: See http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/27891/what-are-the-implications-of-diminishing-levels-of-soreness-in-delayed-onset-mus and Eric's answer.

Comment: How long have you been doing the described workout routine? The lack of DOMS isn't necessarily a bad thing, but if you've been doing the same routine for a long time your body tends to adapt and that's when you replan your workouts to keep progressing.

Comment: 2 months, starting December I'm getting a new routine @JohnL.

Comment: Ok. Two months isn't (in my opinion) too long with one routine, but feel free to mix it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you make no mention of your training goals or experience, so, I'll assume it's general fitness.  With that in mind, I'd say that using DOMS as a goal...

> “IMHO I think DOMS are awesome, it's like rewarding pain”

...is not appropriate.

While there are several posts regarding DOMS on this site, I would refer you to [the one I wrote](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/27365/why-i-never-feel-doms-on-my-abs/27370#27370) on the relationship between DOMS and muscle hypertophy.  It addresses a specific body part, but, is applicable in your instance.  You'll see that DOMS is not necessarily a good goal.  The absence of DOMS does **not** imply lack of improvement.  It's simply an indicator of micro trauma to the muscle tissues caused by [exercises that emphasize the eccentric phase (lengthening or stretching of the muscle)](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/27365/why-i-never-feel-doms-on-my-abs/27370#27370).

Comment: I don't necessarily see it as a goal, but I don't feel like I did bust my ass off working out, I feel like the workout was useless. If that makes sense

Comment: It does make sense, but, you should try not to use DOMS as an indicator of workout success. Keep in mind, as your body adapts to the stress, DOMS is less likely to happen.

Comment: Then what's the psychological approach? Since its clearly just in my mind

Comment: There is no *the* psychological approach. We don't know what yours would be. But you should be able to feel muscle fatigue when you get home. That's what I use as an indicator.

Comment: I do feel tired the couple of hours after the workout, but the day after it's like nothing, I don't feel tired, I don't feel sore. @Alec

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton - It's really an individual thing. I'm at work, day after leg day right now, and I'm not sore, but I can distinctly feel that my quads are very tired still. If you feel completely rested, you could probably train more often, and still have your body get the restitution it needs.

Comment: @Alec I train monday - friday should I add sat and sunday as well?

Comment: Nah, if you already train 5 days a week, I'd say it's enough. Most people get burned out doing 7 days a week. Even the biggest of biggies rarely go over 6. But if you do 5, at least that explains why you're not having DOMS, because DOMS is usually experienced when you've done something your body isn't used to.