# Dumbell routine issue

Tags: dumbbells

Been doing weights the last few weeks now.  Leaving my ego at the door - I'm a small build kinda guy.  I started off at 5kg then worked my way up to 10. I'm currently doing 8-12 reps of bicep curls, hammer curl and concentration curls but I'm beat after one set.. my arms can barely make 5 reps on the next set? Should I lower the weight?  Also, is this routine ok for arms? My arms are not sore the next morning anymore after being totally beat the previous day.. should they be? What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

[Soreness is not at all related to the effectiveness of exercise](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19157/7091).

I would very much recommend [a comprehensive strength training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091). It will give you much faster results all over your entire body, including your biceps.

The problem you're having is that doing some curls is not an effective way to build strength, at all. While curls are one of the most widely recognized strength exercises, they're arguably the most ineffective use of your time, or certainly in competition with others like the Smith machine and quarter squats.

Comment: _"While curls are one of the most widely recognized strength exercises, they're arguably the most ineffective use of your time, or certainly in competition with others like the Smith machine and quarter squats"_ - Is this your opinion, or, based on research?  If opinion, you should state it as such.

Comment: You can look at *every* successful strength training program and look at the complete absence of curls as a start? Rippetoe and Kilgore point it out specifically in Starting Strength as such. Is it the devil? Of course not. But it's in the realm of calf raises and lateral raises as an accessory exercise which gets treated, like the Questioner is doing, as *the* core exercise, usually followed by a bench press. It's the quintessential "mirror muscles" problem.

Comment: That may be the case, but, the question specifically addressed biceps curls etc.  Your answer steers the OP to a program that you consistently espouse as being the best to use without consideration for his goals.  Couple that with the assumption that the absence of an exercise from a program you adhere to implies it's not worth doing is unfair to the OP without knowing the extent of his training program.

Comment: It's *my* answer; I don't go around here disagreeing with others too much unless I have some serious evidence to the contrary. If the community likes my answer, it gets upvoted. If not, down it goes. And yeah, I'm going to espouse comprehensive and effective strength training programs targeted towards beginners when someone seems to be a beginner and is looking for advice. And it's not irrelevant: his curl strength *really will* improve if he flips to bb rows and chin ups, more so than if he keeps curling.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try something in addition, try to do 4 sets as much reps of chins you can, and after that do 5 sets of 20 reps with 5 kg of your curls. I bet you will be sore the next day. However, if you succeed in doing all 5 sets of 20 with 5kg, simply add 1 or 2 kg more so you have a new challenge. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently doing 8-12 reps of bicep curls, hammer curl and concentration curls...is this routine ok for arms?

Cutting-edge research shows that curls are not the only exercise. Consider the addition of other movements, like overhead presses, Turkish get-ups, or "skullcrusher" tricep extensions.