# Questions about working out

Tags: weightlifting, workout

I started going to the gym about 3 weeks ago and I'm confused about some things:

1. When I started, my muscles were sore after the workout and I did some research and found out that it's completely normal. But now, I don't feel any soreness again. I've tried increasing the weight of everything I'm doing but I'd only get tired when lifting but I won't feel any soreness at night or the day after. Is this normal?
2. I feel more energetic after each workout. The only thing I take before going to the gym is a small coffee (without sugar/cream) from Tim Hortons and nothing else (I'm always fasting). I spend about 2 hours doing a full body workout. Why do I feel more energetic after I'm done?
3. I started doing deadlifts but I could keep on doing it for as long as 7 sets. I'd only need to take about 30 seconds rest before I'm ready again. Increasing the weight didn't have any effect. As long as I can lift it from the ground, I can do Multiple sets with 5-9 reps. Is this okay/normal? I've asked people to check my form and they said it's fine (I also don't feel any pain after doing deadlifts)

I'm a male, 18 years, 5'6, annoying stomach fat(around 17%), 153lbs

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Soreness**

You were (and will again) experience [DOMS](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19155/why-do-my-muscles-ache-the-day-after-i-lift-how-come-not-asap-after-my-workout/19157#19157). It has absolutely nothing to do with the effectiveness of a training program, and is related to new exercises and some particular movements which lengthen muscles (like a [dumbbell flat bench fly](https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/DBFly)).

**Energetic**

Your body and mind are running at full throttle. Blood pressure and pulse are up, and if you're working out for two hours [you're releasing endorphins.](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/319157.php) This is actually a reason some people don't workout within a few hours of bedtime as it can be hard to fall asleep.

> The level of plasma β-endorphin [beta-endorphin] is usually elevated
>   during intense exercise...

**Deadlifts**

The rather haphazard nature of how you're lifting will get you into trouble. I highly recommend [you read this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091) and follow the references found within. There are certain activities that you can have decent success with by just going at with random help from the Internet. Progressive overload strength training is not one of those areas. You need to follow a plan otherwise you will get hurt, will not make significant progress, or probably both.